# Link is not work in entire row

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Data Retrieve</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <style>
        #p1{
            background-color:purple;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #home{
          width: 45px;
        }
        #back{
          width: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        include 'dept_list.php';

        $req_id = $_GET['id'];

        if(isset($getdata_arr[$req_id])){
              $load_url = $getdata_arr[$req_id];
              $load_data = file_get_contents($load_url);
              $getData = json_decode($load_data);
              $length = count($getData->data);

              $load_min_data = file_get_contents('ministri.json');
              $getDataMin = json_decode($load_min_data);

              $currentPage =  'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

              foreach ($getDataMin->data as $key => $value) {
                if($value->id == $req_id)
                {
                    $headername = $value->sitename_bn;
                }
              }

              $bn_digits=array('০','১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯');
              $output = str_replace(range(0, 9),$bn_digits, $length);

              /*echo '<pre>';
              print_r($getData);
              echo '</pre>';*/
                    echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
                    echo '<div class="row">';
                    echo '<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">';
                    echo '<table id="info_table" class="table">';
                    echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td><p align='center'><span style='float:left'><a href='http://localhost/directory/montronaloy.html'><img src='back.png' id='back'></a></span><b>";echo $headername; echo"</b><span style='float: right'><a href='http://localhost/directory/BangladeshDirectory.html'><img src='home.png' id='home'></a></span><span style='float: right'><a href='".$currentPage."'><img src='refresh.png' id='refresh'></a></span></p></td>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td align='center' id='p1'>মোট কার্যালয় ( "; echo $output; echo" )</td>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';

              foreach ($getData->data as $key => $value) {
                    /*echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($value);
                    echo '</pre>';
                    die();*/

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . '<a href="next.php?domain_id='.$value->id.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.$value->sitename_bn.'<span style="float: right"> > </span>'.'</a>'."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

              }
              echo '</table>';
              echo '</div>';
          }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: link is not work correctly]

**First Problem**

Here the problem is that the link is not work correctly.  I want to give the link in my entire row, so that any place of the row I click, the link will be work.  But here the links work only on the value and (>) sign.  How can I give the link in entire row.

**Second problem**

At the end of the last value, I do not get any horizontal line.

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML (from the DOM, or from 'view source'); once the server's sent the result of the PHP script to the browser the php is entirely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: The last value horizontal line is solved via CSS.  Look at how your table is styled using the browser's debug mode (ex. F12 on Chrome).  It will show you what CSS applies to your table, and you can add the missing line.

Answer (score 1):

You may use onclick handler on `<tr>` to do.

Replace the `echo '<tr>';` in foreach as below:

```
echo '<tr onclick="document.location.href=\'next.php?domain_id='.$value->id.'\'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
echo "<td>" . '<a href="next.php?domain_id='.$value->id.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.$value->sitename_bn.'<span style="float: right"> > </span>'.'</a>'."</td>";
```

with

```
echo "<td>" . '<a href="next.php?domain_id='.$value->id.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.$value->sitename_bn.'<span style="float: right"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:24px"></i> </span>'.'</a>'."</td>";
```

use Fontawesome icons.